# Django - Using different models in different environments

Tags: python, django, django-models, architecture, django-forms

We have a django application that is, at its core, a series of webpages with Forms which our users fill out in order.  (We'll call the particular series of pages with forms on them a "flow".)

We will be white-labeling this application for a Partner -- the Partner will want to add some fields and even add some webpages with their own new Forms.  This may result in a new order in which the Forms are filled out.  (A new "flow", in addition to changes to existing Forms/Models or new Forms/Models.)

What is the best way to extend our existing, simple Forms-and-Models structure to use different Forms and Models depending on the running instance of the app (e.g. an environment variable)?  Some things we thought about:

- implement something like get_user_model for every Model and Form use in the app, which would look at the current environment
- implement a more generic key-value store so that we're not bound by the current implementation's field types (i.e., have the data field name be part of the data as well)
- a data model which tracks this particular environment's "flow" and which models it needs to use
- subclass existing Models and Forms for each new white-label implementation

Answer (score 0):

*Model Field injection* may be what you are looking for, take a look of [this article](http://blog.jupo.org/2011/11/10/django-model-field-injection/)

> The approach boils down to three concepts:
>
> - Dynamically adding fields to model classes Ensuring Django’s model
> - system respects the new fields
> - Getting the load ordering correct for the above to work

**[Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/)** has done a beautiful job implementing this model field injection with dynamic extra models via `EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS`